How to Implement an Offline Page for a Flask App Using a Service Worker?
I'm working on a Flask web application and I want to implement an offline page that displays when the user is offline or the server is down. I’ve set up a basic Flask app and a service worker, but I’m having trouble getting the offline page to display correctly when the internet is disconnected or the server is down.
app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/offline')
def offline():
    return render_template('offline.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

static/service-worker.js
const CACHE_NAME = 'my-cache-v1';
const urlsToCache = [
    '/',
    '/offline',
    '/static/styles.css',
    // Add other URLs you want to cache
];

self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
            .then(cache => cache.addAll(urlsToCache))
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then(response => response || fetch(event.request))
    );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    const cacheWhitelist = [CACHE_NAME];
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(cacheNames =>
            Promise.all(
                cacheNames.map(cacheName => {
                    if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
                        return caches.delete(cacheName);
                    }
                })
            )
        )
    );
});

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Flask App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to My Flask App!</h1>
    <!-- Content of your main page -->
    <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/static/sw.js')
            .then(function(registration) {
                console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', error);
            });
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>

offline.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Offline</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Oops! It looks like you're offline.</h1>
    <p>Please check your internet connection or try again later.</p>
</body>
</html>

Problem:
When I turn off the Wi-Fi or stop the flask app, I don’t see the offline page. Instead, I get the default chrome error page. What can I do to fix it?
Thank you!

Is your service worker getting registered? Can you check the console if it giving any error. You are trying to register service worker with file name 'sw.js' but your file name is 'service-worker.js'

yes, I checked the 'sw.js' file and it's logged and active.

Can you try using "url_for" path. someting like this
navigator.serviceWorker.register("{{ url_for('static', filename='service-worker.js') }}")
